# Problems detecting collision (Eyeshot) in an array of Tasks

Tags: task, collision, detection, eyeshot

I'm trying to check for each movement in a different task and after checking if there was a collision, in some iterations it generates an Exception "A source matrix was not long or sufficient. Check the index and length, as well as the lower limits of the matrix."
If you try to run sequentially in a "for" the error does not occur, I need to run in parallel to increase performance.
In debugging tests I notice that the error always occurs when trying to run cd.DoWork()

```
   private void btn_Tasks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The source of your work items, create a sequence of Task instances.
        Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(0,tabelaPosicao.Count).Select(i =>
            // Create task here.
            Task.Run(() =>
            {                    
                VerifiCollision(i);

            })

        // No signalling, no anything.
        ).ToArray();

        // Wait on all the tasks.
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    }
   private void VerifiCollision(object x)
    {
        int xx = (int)x;

        int AuxIncrMorsa = Convert.ToInt32(tabelaPosicao[xx].Posicao) * -1;
        bRef_BaseMorsa.Transformation = new Translation(0, AuxIncrMorsa, 0);

        CollisionDetection cd = new CollisionDetection(new List<Entity>() { bRef_BaseMorsa }, new List<Entity>() { bRef_Matriz }, model1.Blocks, true, CollisionDetection2D.collisionCheckType.OBWithSubdivisionTree, maxTrianglesNumForOctreeNode: 5);

        {
            if (cd != null)
            {
                try
                {
                     cd.DoWork();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.StackTrace;
                }
                catch (AggregateException ae)
                {
                    var messege = ae.Message;
                }
            }

            model1.Entities.ClearSelection();

            if (cd3.Result != null && cd3.Result.Count > 0)
            {

              tabelaPosicao[xx].Tuple = new Tuple<string, string>(cd3.Result[0].Item1.ParentName, 
              cd3.Result[0].Item2.ParentName);

            }
         }

    }
```

Comment: This question is too broad akin to debugging an issue

Answer (score 0):

Before applying the transformation you need to clone the entity. 
You can have a look at the "WORKFLOW" topic of [this article](https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011559320).

Comment: You talked about cloning entities, it's probably that I'm not doing it the right way. It could show in a brief example. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the entity.Clone() method. For example, you can clone a Mesh entity in this way: Mesh mesh2 = (Mesh)mesh1.Clone();

Comment: I import from a ".step" file and add it to the EntityList. Next, I add this EntityList to a Block and create a BlockReference.
For each Block and BlockReference clone do I have to clone the entities within the EntityList?

Comment: I am not convinced that clone will help. He his still calling the viewport.DoWork in multiple threads at the same time and he also call in multithread the ClearSelection which mean he has something that gets selected, the get selection will clear at large the entities not just in his task context.

Comment: Please provide some more code or a small Visual Studio sample on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by cloning the Bloks and BlockReference, so each iteration with its transformation performed separately, so there was no possibility that the transformation of one iteration would interfere with another. Grateful for the help.